Making text box above already centered container
Im trying to make a informative text box and i feel like the answer should be pretty simple but im overlooking something. After a few tries and also checking the mighty GPT im coming here for advice.
Currently it looks like this

And i want it to look something like this, where the marked area is the text box

The code is the following


document.getElementById("password").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var password = this.value.trim(); // Trim to remove leading and trailing spaces
  var capitalCheck = document.getElementById("capitalCheck").querySelector(".indicator");
  var numberCheck = document.getElementById("numberCheck").querySelector(".indicator");
  var symbolCheck = document.getElementById("symbolCheck").querySelector(".indicator");

  capitalCheck.textContent = /[A-Z]/.test(password) ? '✔' : '✘';
  numberCheck.textContent = /\d/.test(password) ? '✔' : '✘';
  symbolCheck.textContent = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|,.<>/?]/.test(password) ? '✔' : '✘';

  capitalCheck.style.visibility = /[A-Z]/.test(password) ? "visible" : "visible";
  numberCheck.style.visibility = /\d/.test(password) ? "visible" : "visible";
  symbolCheck.style.visibility = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|,.<>/?]/.test(password) ? "visible" : "visible";
});


function calculateTime() {
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var charCount = password.length;
  var hasUpperCase = /[A-Z]/.test(password);
  var hasNumber = /\d/.test(password);
  var hasSymbol = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|,.<>/?]/.test(password);

  var possibleCharacters = 26 + (hasUpperCase ? 26 : 0) + (hasNumber ? 10 : 0) + (hasSymbol ? 32 : 0); // lowercase letters + uppercase letters + numbers + symbols
  var permutations = Math.pow(possibleCharacters, charCount);

  var seconds = permutations / 1000000000; // divide by 1 billion to convert to seconds
  var minutes = seconds / 60;
  var hours = minutes / 60;
  var days = hours / 24;
  var years = days / 365;

  var result = "It would take approximately ";
  if (years >= 1) {
    result += Math.floor(years) + " years, " + Math.floor(days % 365) + " days, " + Math.floor(hours % 24) + " hours, " + Math.floor(minutes % 60) + " minutes, and " + Math.floor(seconds % 60) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  } else if (days >= 1) {
    result += Math.floor(days) + " days, " + Math.floor(hours % 24) + " hours, " + Math.floor(minutes % 60) + " minutes, and " + Math.floor(seconds % 60) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  } else if (hours >= 1) {
    result += Math.floor(hours) + " hours, " + Math.floor(minutes % 60) + " minutes, and " + Math.floor(seconds % 60) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  } else if (minutes >= 1) {
    result += Math.floor(minutes) + " minutes, and " + Math.floor(seconds % 60) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  } else {
    result += Math.ceil(seconds) + " seconds to crack this password.";
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
}
/* styles.scss */


/* Informative Text Box Container */

.info-container {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Center text */
}


/* Main Content Container */

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  /* Adjusted padding to match the informative text box */
  width: 400px;
  /* Matched width with .article.container */
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


/* Additional styles */

.criteria-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Rest of your existing styles */

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container>h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

label {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type="password"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #0056b3;
}

p#result {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.criteria {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul.criteria>li {
  font-size: 16px;
}

span.indicator {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
}

span.valid {
  color: green;
}
<!-- Informative Text Box Container -->
<div class="info-container">
  <p>This is an informative text box. It provides guidelines for creating a strong password.</p>
</div>

<!-- Main Content Container -->
<div class="container">
  <h1>Password Strength Checker</h1>
  <label for="password">Enter Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <div class="criteria">
    <div class="criteria-item" id="capitalCheck">Capital Letters: <span class="indicator"></span></div>
    <div class="criteria-item" id="numberCheck">Numbers: <span class="indicator"></span></div>
    <div class="criteria-item" id="symbolCheck">Symbols: <span class="indicator"></span></div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="calculateTime()">Calculate</button>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>



Here is the original SCSS


/* styles.scss */


/* Informative Text Box Container */

.info-container {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Center text */
}


/* Main Content Container */

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  /* Adjusted padding to match the informative text box */
  width: 400px;
  /* Matched width with .article.container */
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


/* Additional styles */

.criteria-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Rest of your existing styles */

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container>h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

label {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type="password"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #0056b3;
}

p#result {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.criteria {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul.criteria>li {
  font-size: 16px;
}

span.indicator {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
}

span.valid {
  color: green;
}




Do you need to stack one below the other ?

Yea i want the one on top of the other, so the text box is above the password checker

I made you the snippet you could have made too. Do we actually even need to see the JS?

Just add this to the scss or css (this is based on your html)
CSS  or SCSS :
body {
   /** rest of the css **/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;        
  }


You could use relative positioning.
If you have any element, you can set the css property position to the value relative, the child to absolute then use the top, right, left, or bottom properties to position the element with respect to it's parent.
Here's an example:


.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background: lightgreen;
}
<div class="parent">
  Here is some content with position relative in normal layout flow
  <div class="child">
    Here is some content with position absolute
    positioned in relation to it's parent
  </div>
</div>




just put both the divs in another div and add this css to it
(    display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center; )
